# Show the minimum ticks in Y axis JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

Is there anyway to set the minimum ticks in Y axis? i have tried this:

```
plot1 = $.jqplot('graphCanvas', [<?php echo $line1; ?>], {
                animate: true,
                series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
                axesDefaults: {
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: -30,
                        fontSize: '10pt'
                    },
                    showMinorTicks:true
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    }, 
                    yaxis:{

                    }
                }
            });
```

Even with my showMinor ticks set to true, The Y axis always shows 3 times the biggest value for example: if 12 is my biggest value biggest thick is 36, how can i limit it by 14 or 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In y axis option we can set

```
yaxis : {
        min : 0,
        tickInterval : 1                
        }
```

or

```
yaxis : {
        min : 0,
        tickInterval : 1,
            max:14              
        }
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1766/)